# ラズパイ使用で車とcan通信

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry pi3 B+と以下のモジュールで車とのCAN通信を試みております。

[MCP2515 TJA1050 CAN バス モジュール for Arduino (Amazon)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B01LX9JSA4/)

mcp2515のVccは基板から浮かせて3.3v供給するように施工し以下サイトを参考にさせていただき進めました。
[Raspberry Pi CAN通信 (MCP2515 TJA1050 CAN Bus Module) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/mt08/items/535ab4690eecbcf5375d)

しかし、ifconfig コマンドで（不明なネット）と出てしまい上手く通信出来ているかもわかりません。
以下、シェル上の状態を記載させていただきます。

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep spi
[    5.582520] mcp251x spi0.0 can0: MCP2515 successfully initialized.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig can0
can0: flags=128<NOARP>  mtu 16
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 10  (不明なネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ご経験のある方がいればこの状態がどの様な状態なのか、例えば結局mcp2515もしくはTJA1050が上手く作動していない等々、何か分かることがありましたらアドバイス頂きたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参照されている記事でも同様なのですが、Up link を行っていませんね。`sudo ip link set can0 up` を実行してみて下さい。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。アドバイス頂いた事やれる状態になったら行って報告いたします。

Comment: RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argumentと出ます。やはり上手く繋がってないという事でしょうか？

Comment: `sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000` を実行した際には何かエラーメッセージが表示されましたでしょうか？

Comment: お世話になります。特にエラーも出ず次の行にpi@raspberry〜と出ます。ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: いろいろとご教授ありがとうございました。とりあえずsudo ip link set can0 upを含めいろいろ追加した結果、車とのCAN通信ができるようになりました。とはいえcandump can0コマンドでデータがバーっと出てくる状態でどう処理して良いのかわかりません。最終目的はECU ROMデータ吸い出し、編集、書き込みなのでもしその辺り何かご経験、情報ありましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: いえいえ、何のお役にも立てませんでした。。。こちらの質問については通信ができる様になるまでの手順を回答として書いてみてはどうでしょうか(自己承認が可能です)。また、データ吸い出し以降については別質問を立てる方がよろしいかと思います。

Comment: 了解です。別質問立てます。備忘録として手順は後々整理してから載せます。お世話になりました。